# Zip code size test C#

Tags: c#-4.0, street-address, maskedtextbox

I have a small piece of code that I have been trying to get to work, but nope. So I've come to the experts. I'm trying to test a zip code entry and limit it to 5 digits only. My first issue is with the attached code. It doesn't seem to be counting  the length properly. Also, how can I limit the user so if they try to type a 6th character, it won't show or be accepted?

```
private void textBoxZip_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        String userInputString;
        int length,
            max = 5;

        userInputString = textBoxZip.Text;
        numberTest(userInputString);

        length = userInputString.Length;
        if (length > max)
        {
            labelErrorMessage.Text = "Maximum length 5 numbers";
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think using a [MaskedTextBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.maskedtextbox.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1) would be an easy solution. This will allow you to easily accept only a certain # of characters in a specified format.

The MaskedTextBox is a standard .NET control in the control toolbar in Visual Studio.

Comment: This was a great suggestion as it corrected a couple of issues I had elsewhere. Question though. Is there a way to make the ________ go away? I just want a blank space.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't know of a way to get rid of that line.

Comment: Found the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1459797/hiding-the-promptchar-for-nets-maskedtextbox

Answer (score 0):

You should look at events `KeyDown` and `KeyPress`. See example in [MSDN Control.KeyPress Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.keypress%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

If you are in a WinForms application, you can limit a textbox's length by setting the MaxLength property.